# Elo Touchscreen on Debian has partial X-axis

Tags: debian, touch-screen

I have an Elo Touchscreen that I'm hooking up to a Debian Wheezy machine. The screen itself works great, but I'm having trouble with the touchscreen part. This is an Elo E509854 (EloTouchSystems,Inc Elo TouchSystems 2216 AccuTouch® USB Touchmonitor Interface). It hooks up with 2 cables - VGA for the monitor, USB for the touch input.

I have 2 identical monitors, and I had hooked one of them (not sure which one) up previously, and gone through flipping the Y-axis and calibrating the touchscreen area so that it tracked your finger correctly.

The problem I'm having now is that when I run evtest, the ABS_X only outputs on approximately the top left 1/4 of the screen (it runs from ~300 on the left of the screen, to 185 in the middle). Everywhere else, I get ABS_Y only - along with MSC_SCAN, ABS_MSC, etc... just no ABS_X.

When I tried calibrating anyway, the mouse tracks up and down in Y semi-OK (the calibration seems a little off), but the mouse wants to stay against the left side of the screen (or the right side if I invert the X-axis). If I move in the top-left corner of the screen, the mouse bounces left-to-right rapidly.

Not sure if it's part of it, but the Y-axis seems skewed ... the readings go something like this:

```
TOP L ~ 3400                                TOP R ~ 2500



BOTTOM L ~ 600                               BOTTOM R ~ 1500
```

Any ideas on what to try? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me. The reason is that the touchscreen is detected as a mouse. Can you put the xorg logs?

Comment: I will try to ... it may take a few days, as that monitor is on a CNC machine and I have to transfer any files via flash drive.